# The expectation of product of three random variables

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have the following setup:

1. ( A ) is an ( $M \times N$ ) matrix with entries ( $A \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(\nu_{nk})$ ).
2. ( B ) is a ( $N \times N$ ) matrix with entries ( $B \sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ ).
3. ( A ) and ( B ) are independent, implying ( $\mathbb{E}[AB] = 0 $).

I think the diagonal entries of ( A ), because ( $a_{ij}$ ) is Bernoulli-distributed, must be ( $a_{ii}^2 = a_{ii}$ ) and it leads to
[ $\mathbb{E}\big[(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T)_{ii}\big] = \sum_{j=1}^M \nu_{ij}$ ].
Now for off-diagonal entries, it should be
[ $\mathbb{E}\big[(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T)_{ij}\big] = \sum_{k=1}^M \nu_{ik}\nu_{jk}$ ]
given that ( $\mathbf{A}_{ik}$ ) and ( $\mathbf{A}_{jk}$ ) are independent for ($ i \neq j$ ).

My question: If $\eta=ABA^T$, how can I compute $\mathbb{E}[\eta]$ with respect to both A and B?

Comment: Condition on $A$ and you have $\mathbb{E}[\eta\mid A]=\mu A\mathbf{1}A^T$ (where $\mathbf{1}$ is the matrix of all 1s) and so ...

Comment: @user10354138 It is not a conditional expectation.

Comment: So?  Recall Law of iterated expectation.

Comment: @user10354138 do you mean something like this $\mathbb{E}_{q(A)}\Bigg[\mathbb{E}_{q(B)}\Big[\mathbb{E}_{q(A)}\big[\eta|B,A\big]|A\Big]\Bigg]$?

Answer (score 2):

Condition on $A$, then compute the conditional expectation of $\eta$ conditioned on $A$ (using the fact that $A,B$ are independent), then sum over all choices for $A$.

Let's compute $\mathbb{E}[\eta_{1,2}]$.  The calculation will be similar for any other entry of $\eta$.  We have

$$\eta_{1,2} = \sum_{i,j} A_{1,i} B_{i,j} A_{2,j}.$$

Note that $A_{1,i} A_{2,j}$ is either $1$ (if $A_{1,i} = A_{2,j} = 1$) or $0$ (otherwise).  Let's define $W$ to be the number of such $1$'s, i.e.,

$$W = \sum_{i,j} A_{1,i} A_{2,j} = \sum_i A_{1,i} \sum_j A_{2,j}.$$

Let's let $U= \sum_i A_{1,i}$ and $V= \sum_j A_{2,j}$, so that $W=UV$.    Now $\eta_{1,2}$ is the sum of $W$ i.i.d. r.v.'s with distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$, so by linearity of expectation,

$$\mathbb{E}[\eta_{1,2} | W=w] = w \mu$$

and therefore $\mathbb{E}[\eta_{1,2} | W] = W \mu$.  Applying the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), we see

$$\mathbb{E}[\eta_{1,2}] = \mathbb{E}_W[\mathbb{E}[\eta_{1,2}|W]] = \mathbb{E}[W \mu] = \mu \mathbb{E}[W].$$

Now as we wrote above, $W=UV$.  You can note that $U,V$ are independent, hence

$$\mathbb{E}[W] = \mathbb{E}[U] \mathbb{E}[V]
= \sum_i \nu_{1,i} \sum_j \nu_{2,j}.$$

Plugging in, we find that

$$\mathbb{E}[\eta_{1,2}] = \mu \sum_i \nu_{1,i} \sum_j \nu_{2,j}.$$

The same result applies for $\mathbb{E}[\eta_{k,\ell}]$ whenever $k \ne \ell$.

When $k=\ell$, you need to adjust the above computation slightly, replacing $\mathbb{E}[W]=\mathbb{E}[U] \mathbb{E}[V]$ with $\mathbb{E}[W]=\mathbb{E}[U]$ (as in this case $U=V$ and $UV=U^2=U$ for 0-or-1-valued vectors), then adjusting the rest of the calculation accordingly.

Comment: Why are you dividing by $N^2$?  OP already knew $\mathbb{E}[(AA^T)_{ii}]$.

Comment: @user10354138, Oops, sorry about dividing by $N^2$!  That was my error.  I've corrected it.  Yes, you're right, perhaps that part of the calculation was unnecessary. Oh well, I think there is plenty of value in the rest of the answer.  Hopefully it's still valuable to have a self-contained, detailed answer to the question.